# bootstrap-select with flask

Tags: python, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, flask, bootstrap-select

I tried to used bootstrap-select whith the following example, but in Flask I get only one value and not the maximum two values?

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="{{url_for('compare')}}" method="get" role="form">
  <div class="input-group"> 
<span class="input-group-addon">Tests:</span>
  <select name='tests' class="selectpicker show-menu-arrow form-control" multiple data-max-options="2" data-live-search="true">
      <option value="Test1">Test1</option>
      <option value="Test2">Test2</option>
      <option value="Test3">Test3</option>
  </select>
  <span class="input-group-btn">
    <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Search!</button>
  </span>
</div>
</form>
<hr>
```

The route in Flask is define like below:

```
@app.route("/compare/", methods=["GET"])
@templated('compare.tmpl')
def compare():
   tests = request.args.get('tests')
```

How is it possible to get maximum two selected values in flask e.g. Test1 and Test2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`request.args` is a `MultiDict`. It provides a method called `getlist` that will return a list of items for the given key rather than a single value. Update your code to the following.

```
tests = request.args.getlist('tests')
```

More information can be found in the [`werkzeug` documentation](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.9/datastructures/#werkzeug.datastructures.MultiDict.getlist).